# Creating a Calculated Field between 2 datasets in SSRS 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql, reporting-services, calculated-field

I have a very simple task. I have two datsets. The first is a single value that has returned me a number of calls that has been made. The second is a list of targets. I want to be able to divide the first number of calls by its call target in order to calculate the total %.

The lookups of these are dependant on the criteria that is selected in the report itself. I know it's possible to do inside SQL its just a huge pain in the ass. I want to be able to calculate two fields and I thought something so simple would be a breeze for SSRS but apparently not. So the error i get is:

```
*The expression used for the calculated field'=fields!DMCP.Value / FIRST(Fields!DMCTarget.Value,"AllTargets")' includes an aggregate,rownumber,runningvalue, previous or lookup function. aggregate,rownumber,runningvalue, previous and lookup functions cannot be used in calculated field expressions.*
```

I can take the first function out but it doesn't help me. It says it can only calculate in the same dataset, problem is these values can never co-exist in the same dataset. Anything I can do????

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is better to do this in SQL, otherwise you have to take injection of a lookup in ur ...

Comment: @SQL_Kid Are you putting this calculation in a table, textbox, or list?  Also, when you say that one of your datasets has a single value, do you mean that it has a single column/field with multiple records or that it has a single column/field containing only 1 record?  I tried to replicate what you were doing and succeeded with no problem, so I must be missing something.

Comment: Why not just move `=fields!DMCP.Value / FIRST(Fields!DMCTarget.Value,"AllTargets")` to the report body?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I was on a really tight turnaround so I opted to do the calculations in SQL Server instead. Basically for anyone who comes across the same issues in the future, I can't seem to use a Column from 1 dataset and use that to create a calculated field if the second column that creates the aggregate is apart of another dataset. Looking back, im not sure my original question reflected that right. But anyway, whats done is done. Thanks again